# plesk mysql reporting different version in cli to a version query

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, plesk

I'm trying to upgrade a Plesk server running Ubuntu (12.04.2 LTS) and when doing a query check on apt-cache:

```
apt-cache policy mysql-server
```

... it reports that I have the latest 5.5. branch already installed. which is 5.5.52

However when I do a mysql version query command it reports a much earlier version of mysql.

How could I have a difference in versions, is there more than one copy installed and if so how do I update the version on my actual domain which seems to be out of date.

Comment: I'm having the same question on Ubuntu 14.04, `mysql -V` reports 5.5.50 while `apt-cache policy mysql-server` reports 5.5.53. I also tried rebooting. Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Hi no I didn't.  I did restart the server as well but it didn't change.